# How do I load a simple script?

Tags: windbg

I want to experiment with using program scripts but WinDbg cannot find the script file.
It says:

```
Command file execution failed, Win32 error 0n2
"The system cannot find the file specified."
```

The test script is from right out of WinDbg's help docs (saved as C:\tmp\file.txt):

```
.echo The first argument is ${$arg1}.
.echo The second argument is ${$arg2}.
```

The command I'm using is likewise from WinDbg's help docs:

```
$$>a< "C:\tmp\file.txt" myFirstArg mySecondArg
```

I've tried putting the file in different locations.  I've also tried putting the script in the same directory as windbg.exe and not using a path.  I am running as Administrator, so I doubt permissions are the problem.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I was in a debugging session with another host (VM-to-VM) and the script file must be on the **target** computer/VM being debugged, not the computer running WinDbg.

Thanks to Thomas W. for responding.

Comment: are you sure the script needs to be on target and not in the host :( it doesn't sound logical suppose you have a very critical debugging issue and you need to employ 50000 scripts that you developed over the lifeime of your career you mean to say that you provide every script that you live upon to an unknown remote system that you are debuging ? you must ave changed several inputs and it must have worked due to another cause and you are probably wrongly attributing results to an arbitrary factor

Comment: Your logic is sound, blabb, it doesn't make sense to me either to have to put scripts on the target.  [sigh] But I just re-ran my test to prove to myself the script isn't found if on my debugging system.  It does indeed load and run if on the target.  It is entirely possible it's due to a configuration issue with WinDbg, but I don't know what/where to look in WinDbg to winnow out that  info (I'd be interesting to know, though).  I really do appreciate your chiming in with your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the backslashes:

```
$$>a< "C:\\tmp\\file.txt" myFirstArg mySecondArg
```

Or omit the quotation marks as long as you don't have spaces in the file name:

```
$$>a< C:\tmp\file.txt myFirstArg mySecondArg
```